# Mongoose and Node - Implementing Roles - Best practices

Tags: node.js, mongoose, roles

I am working on a token based application, and I want to apply roles for different types of user. 
My question is if it is a better practice to create a model "Group" and in the model "User" and reference that model "Group" to the user_role property in "User" model.
It would be like this: (I haven't started yet so I can not copy real code, this is just for demonstrative purposes)

```
const GroupSchema = new Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['admin', 'employee', 'guest']
  },
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({ 
  role: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Group'
  },
},

...
```

On the other hand I I thought doing this:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
}
...
```

But I don't really know what would be the advantages and disadvantages of using one or the other, regarding scalability basically, and if there is a better way.

Comment: Keep it simple and just put the role to the user model.

Comment: having a reference for Roles in User Schema you will have a flexibility to add more roles, like a dropdown  of roles in Admin App.